# using a dictionary find the line number a word in a file appears on

Tags: python, file, list, dictionary

So for homework I have to find the line number or numbers a word (given by the list) appears on. So far I have this

```
def index(f,l):
   'str,list(str)==nonetype'
    infile=open(f)
    file=infile.read()
    b=file.split('\n')
    G=file.splitlines()
    infile.close
    count=1
    res=0
    c={}
    a=[]
    for i in b:
        a+=[i]
    for n in l:
        while res <len(G):
            small={G[res]:count}
            c.update(small)
            count+=1
            res+=1
            if (a[res] in c) and (n in a[res]):
                print (n+'{}'.format(c[count]))
```

SO I get here and I get error because its going out of range. i have been working to long cause it all looks like gibberish right now.

Comment: Indent your code. What doesn't work?

Comment: pretty much all of it, I can open the file and get it into a list but then i need to get a dictionary where every word is a key and the values are the line number the word is on

Comment: 1) If someone gave you pen and paper and told you to solve the problem in a way such that he could follow the exact same steps and always come up with exactly the same solution, what would your solution be? 2) What would it look like as pseudocode? 3) What would it look like as Python source code, roughly? 4) Implement and bug fix 3).

Comment: Try giving yourself an example of the input and output of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def index(filename, wordlist):

    # Initialize some variable with meaningful names

    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            # Do something with the line

    return # something
```

Here are a few more hints that can make your code neater but might be too advanced for now: `enumerate`, `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: enumerate may be helpful to OP also (+1)

Answer (score 0):

since its homework I'll just help you with an algorithm

```
foreach line in the_file:
     if search_word in line:
        print line_number
```

this is only one small step away from python already